# Sql query missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

Keep getting the feedback that there is a missing keyword in my sql query.

```
select sum(transaction_amnt) 
from cs339.comm_to_cand 
join cs339.committee_master 
join cs339.cmte_id_to_geo 
    on cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.comm_to_cand.cmte_id 
    and cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.cmte_id_to_geo.cmte_id 
where cycle=1112 
    and cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM';
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `ON` for your first join -- I added some aliases to this as well:

```
select sum(transaction_amnt) Total
from cs339.comm_to_cand cc
join cs339.committee_master cm
  on cm.cmte_id=cc.cmte_id 
join cs339.cmte_id_to_geo cg
    on cm.cmte_id=cg.cmte_id 
where cycle=1112 
    and cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM';
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no "on" condition after the first join

try this:

```
select sum(transaction_amnt) 
from cs339.comm_to_cand 
join cs339.committee_master 
          on cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.comm_to_cand.cmte_id 
join cs339.cmte_id_to_geo     
    on cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.cmte_id_to_geo.cmte_id 
where cycle=1112 
    and cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM';
```

Comment: select sum(transaction_amnt) from cs339.comm_to_cand join cs339.committee_master on cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.comm_to_cand.cmte_id join cs339.cmte_id_to_geo on and cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.cmte_id_to_geo.cmte_id where cycle=1112 and cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM'

Now I am getting an error that there is a missing expression

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Oracle developer, but the first `JOIN` is missing the `ON` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know if this is true, but my understanding is that you need to provide the "binders" on each join you make, so this should be like this.

select sum(transaction_amnt) 
   from cs339.comm_to_cand 
   join cs339.committee_master on cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.comm_to_cand.cmte_id 
   join cs339.cmte_id_to_geo on  cs339.committee_master.cmte_id=cs339.cmte_id_to_geo.cmte_id 
   where cycle=1112 and cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM';

Also, the columns on the WHERE clause should have their table parent named, so if cycle and cmte_pty_affiliation columns belongs to cs339.comm_to_cand it should be

where cs339.comm_to_cand.cycle=1112 and cs339.comm_to_cand.cmte_pty_affiliation='DEM';